# преобразовать (reshape) Numpy вектор (1D массив) в 2D матрицу забив недостающие элементы NaN's

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, numpy

Мне нужно, чтобы при выходе за границы массива несуществующие элементы заменялись на `nan`

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
a = a.reshape(3, 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы хранить `NaN`'s придется преобразовать массив к типу данных `float*` и воспользоваться [numpy.pad()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
In [117]: new_shape = (3,3)

In [118]: a = (np.pad(a.astype(float),
                      pad_width=(0, np.prod(new_shape)-len(a)),
                      mode='constant', 
                      constant_values=np.nan)
                 .reshape(new_shape))

In [119]: a
Out[119]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

функция [np.pad()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) позволяет растянуть Numpy массивы. Параметр `pad_width` позволяет гибко задавать как и в каком месте мы хотим растянуть массив. В вашем случае мы добавляем 0 элементов перед первым элементом и `9-6` элементов  (`constant_values=np.nan`) после последнего элемента.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Можешь чуть разъяснить код.

Comment: @Deniz, добавил пояснения в ответ